# upload a site slimframework to amazon linux EC2

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, slim

I try to upload my app to the server

I open a server with php.mysql,phpmyadmin

now whan I try to come in I see the files like this:
[image]

my index file is in folder: public

in my server I have a folder and then I have the app like this:
http://ec2-33-194-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/appname/

I put a .htaccess in the folder appname

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

but the system not work :/

Comment: try this `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: i get that error
sudo: a2enmod: command not found

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Open the file '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'.
 2. sudo su
 3. vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
 4. Change the subsequent AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All
 5. sudo service httpd restart
```

It Should work fine.

Comment: Its not work
if u habe a skype plz come to me: haizone